# PHP/SQL Syntax: Error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just a little background- I have never used PHP or MySQL before so I am completely new to this so either I'm just a novice and can't see what I'm doing wrong because I don't know better or I'm exhausted and sick of looking at the same line wondering where I went wrong.

I keep getting this error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 15"

Which I know is a simple syntax error so I went to the line and then went and looked up the manuals and proper syntax so I am just curious if anyone can shed some light on what might be causing this error.

This is a piece of the PHP file I am using and line 15 (which is referred to in the error is the last line which has the ')' and the ';'

```
$sql= 'CREATE TABLE members (
                           yourID INT NOT NULL,
                           firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           telephone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           state VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           theType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity3 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity4 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity5 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           charity6 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                           PRIMARY KEY(catID),
                           )';
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Remove the quote `PRIMARY KEY(catID),` <= *right there*. Questions like these are considered off-topic. Plus, you don't have a `catID` column, you have `yourID`. So that will also fail, which will throw you an unknown column syntax error.

Comment: Very sorry, didn't realize. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma after

```
PRIMARY KEY(catID)
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the  `,` in :

```
.
.
PRIMARY KEY(catID),
                           )';
```